# Viewing Microsoft Graph activity

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Sorry if this question is off topic. I have a tool in C# that works with the Microsoft calendar API using Graph.

Is there anyway that I can view the activity of the app that I wrote? It was a very long time ago when I create the app project and can't find out where the microsoft developer console is. :(

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found it:

https://login.microsoftonline.com

You can access you apps using this portal.

Comment: Can't we find it using app insights or checking in Admin center of Azure ?

Comment: @VinodkumarGI don't have an Azure account I don't think. I certainly am not paying for any subscription. So I don't have those features.

Comment: When I log in I just see office.com where I can see my documents. I would guess that is not the right answer out of today.

Comment: @rekire I agree. I can’t see my app activity on my iPad with this link, #confused